# Iterator is not working

Tags: java, iterator

I was trying to write an iterator for a program of mine, but it seems it is not iterating as it should. I tried to follow an example from online but still.

```
public Iterator<ParkingPlace> iterator(){

    Iterator<ParkingPlace> iterator = new Iterator<ParkingPlace>() {
        int currentIndex =0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentIndex<parking.size() && parking.get(currentIndex)!=null;
        }

        @Override
        public Parking next() {
            if(!hasNext()){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }else if (hasNext()){
                return parking.get(currentIndex++);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    return iterator;
}
```

Where parking is a List of "parking places" defined as

> List < ParkingPlace> parking = new ArrayList();

So, the last part where I define parking is correct, I have checked it and it has all the expected elements.

But my iterator is not giving me back what I expect from him.
My main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parking parking = new Parking();

    //Tests for iterator
    for (ParkingPlace place : parking) {
        System.out.println(parking.iterator());
    }

}
```

Ex. of results:
Parking$1@61bbe9ba
Parking$1@610455d6
Parking$1@511d50c0

Expected results would be:
A0
A1
A2

Ideas where my mistake could be?

Comment: Does `Parking` class implement Iterable?

Comment: yes it implements it

Answer (score 0):

Implement toString() method on Parking class to print the result formatted as you want.